# MYSQL + PHP making an sql excute daily

Tags: php, mysql

I want a daily SQL to execute for people who visit a certain page. However I only want this to happen once every 24 hours with that specific user.

(do i use cookies? What SQL query do I use? What's the PHP code?)

This is how my table looks like:

[image]

and I want to execute a mysql query similar to this:

```
INSERT INTO `user_badges` VALUES ('1', 'ADM', '0');
```

as mentioned above, i want this to execute for users visiting the page in PHP once a day. Thanks.

Comment: Have a table that contains the last time that each user performed the query. Your server should check the table, and see if it's been at least 24 hours, otherwise skip the SQL.

Comment: You need to use a cron job.

Comment: has anyone got any PHP code that could help with this. I really suck.

Comment: You could do this without PHP by redirecting stdin from a file into the **mysql** command line tool.  mysql db_name < script.sql > output.tab

Comment: I want it to be in a PHP so i can echo a message telling the people they've received something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE badge_update_time (
    user_id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY,
    last_updated DATETIME
);
```

Then the script that would insert into the `user_badges` table would first perform a query like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
FROM badge_update_time
WHERE user_id = 1 AND last_updated > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

This will return `count == 0` if there's no row for the user in the table, or the row is older than 1 day. So your code would do:

```
if ($row['count'] == 0) {
    mysqli_execute($conn, "INSERT INTO badge_update_time VALUES (1, NOW()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE last_updated = NOW()";
    mysqli_execute($conn, "INSERT INTO `user_badges` VALUES ('1', 'ADM', '0')");
}
```

Comment: [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PRIMARY KEY,
    last_updated DATETIME
)' at line 2

Comment: Sorry, I left the datatype out. Fixed it now.

Comment: I'm having issues with the php, keep getting error 500.

Comment: If you're getting a 500 error, there should be an error in the PHP log.

Comment: Do you mind putting the first and second query into one? If that's possible

Comment: You can't insert into two tables in one query.

Comment: You never called `mysql_fetch_assoc()` to get the results of the first query.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to do something with MySQL's event scheduler.

Add a column to your application's `users` table like

```
been_there  BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE
```

and when the user visits the page in question,

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE users
                         SET been_there = TRUE
                         WHERE user_id = :user_id");
$stmt->execute(array(":user_id" => $user_id));
$event = "CREATE EVENT reset_" . $user_id . " IF NOT EXISTS
            ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 24 HOUR
            DO
              UPDATE users SET been_there = FALSE WHERE user_id = " . $user_id;
$dbh->exec($event);
```

(Note that I am not normally in favour of using dynamic SQL, however in this case I'm not sure there is any other way and I'm assuming that `$user_id` has already been properly sanitized.)

The big advantage this has over `cron` is that it places scheduled updates to the database under control of the database itself, so that they are unlikely to fail due to circumstances outside the database.

I have *not* tested this to see if the syntax is correct, and I leave error handling as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: this works however, i want it so i get a PHP feedback telling that specific user they've received the thing with an echo

Comment: When do you want to send the message relative to when the user visits the page?